# SHA1-Indexed Hash table in D

Tags: indexing, hashtable, d, sha1

I'm using a D builtin hash table indexed by SHA1-digests (`ubyte[20]`) to relate information in my file system search engine.

Are there any data structures more suitable for this (in D) because of all the nice properties of such a key: uniformly, distributed, random, fixed-sized or will the behaviour of D's builtin hash tables automatically figure out that it could for example just pick the first n (1-8) bytes of a SHA1-digest as a bucket index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the hash function used inside standards maps is trivial enough (cost wise) that it won't make much if any difference unless you are running code that is mostly look-ups. Keep in mind that the full key will be read to do the final comparison so it will get loaded into the cache either way.

OTOH I think there is a `opHash` method you can overload.

Comment: the method you're thinking of is `size_t   toHash() @trusted nothrow;`

Comment: So I guess I just returned the first 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bit) bytes depending on architecture then.

Comment: @Nordlöw, I advice against that idea... :) `toHash()` is used for something else.

Comment: According to http://dlang.org/hash-map.html it should be `hash_t` instead of `size_t` right? And its seems that `opHash` and `toHash` are both used in the docs.

Comment: @DejanLekic, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Isn't it obvious why? toHash() returns a size_t value. If you really want to do that, then I suggest you use CRC32 or MurmurHash2 (because it generates 32 or 64 bit values). I would keep SHA1 hashes, and that is it. You can't be 100% sure your SHA1 hashes will have different first 1-8 bytes ...

Comment: I'm assuming a different usage: `ValType[SHA1ConainerType] map` where the key type holds the the full SHA1 of the value and uses it for equality but only a 32 bits for the initial bucketing.

Comment: @DejanLekic, I believe `toHash` is used as a basis for the bucket index to the Hash Table. The return value of this function doesn't have to be unique for each of its inputs. If `toHash` doesn't exercise all the bits in the return value logic will still work but performance will suffer. My solution do use all bits/bytes in a random way.

Comment: That does make sense indeed, but I could not find any details how is `toHash()` used internally, and quite frankly I can't bother reading the source code, so let's just assume you two are right - in which case what is proposed above will work nicely, so BCS got +1 from me. :)